# What does it mean to call 'self' as a function?

Tags: python

There are a lot of tutorials and sites online that explain the keyword `self` in Python, but none that explain what it means to call `self(param1, param2)`. What is this line of code doing or what function is it calling in the class?

Comment: `self` is not a keyword in Python, so if those resources were saying it was a keyword, then they are not good resources

Comment: Possible duplicates: [What is self() in python?](/q/54555141/4518341), [How can I make a class object callable in Python?](/q/70916141/4518341). See also [What is the purpose of the `self` parameter? Why is it needed?](/q/2709821/4518341) if you need any clearing up about how it's not a keyword.

Answer (score 1):

A class can define a special method `__call__()`, which allows its instances to be used as functions. If the class does this, methods can use `self()` as a function. So

```
self(param1, param2)
```

is equivalent to

```
Classname.__call__(self, param1, param2)
```

(where `Classname` is the class of `self`).

Answer (score -3):

`self` is the default variable of a class. Think of it like the default word for a class.

Take this time class for example:

```
class time:
  def __init__(self, hour, minute, second):
    self.hour = hour
    self.minute = minute
    self.second = second

  def __repr__(self):
    return "%02d:%02d:%02d" % (self.hour, self.minute, self.second)

f = time(10, 30, 57)
print(f.__repr__())
```

Using `self`, we can assign our attributes to the `time` class specifically, that means if we have another attribute named `self.hour` in another class, it would be completely different unless it was the same value or used the `super()` function.

Ex:

```
class time:
  def __init__(self):
    self.hour = 1
    self.minute = 5
    self.second = 32

  def __repr__(self):
    return "%02d:%02d:%02d" % (self.hour, self.minute, self.second)


class MoreTime:
  def __init__(self):
    self.hour = 6
    self.minute = 0
    self.second = 2
  
  def __repr__(self):
    return "%02d:%02d:%02d" % (self.hour, self.minute, self.second)



f = time()

g = MoreTime()


print(f.__repr__())

print(g.__repr__())
```

**Output:**

01:05:32

06:00:02

Note: You do not *HAVE* to use `self`. It is highly recommended to use it because it is the word most used to symbolize an instance of a class. It is used for better readability and its just a good habit to learn. Do note that `self` is not a keyword.

```
class main:
  def __init__(bee):
    bee.string = "Hello World"
  def run(bee):
    return bee.string

d = main()
print(d.run())
```

As you can see, you can define `self` as whatever you want in the initializer. I recommend not using this code above and just use `self`.

Comment: The question is about *calling* `self`, which this doesn't cover.

Comment: BTW, I would avoid calling a class `main` since that's the conventional name of the main function (AKA [entry point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point)). You could do `Main` instead, though that might still be confusing -- depends on the context.